# VBA Click drop-down menu option, when Menu is made out of table elements (on a Web Page)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to choose an option from dropdown menu, that appears to be set in a table where each option has been put into separate tr / td elements like so:

```
<div class="MenuTableContainer">
  <table class="MenuTable" style="width: 175px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody class="MenuTableBody">
    <tr class="MenuTableRow">
       <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">1 Heavy</td>
       <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="1 Heavy"></td></tr>
    <tr class="MenuTableRow">
        <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">2 Medium-Heavy</td>
        <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="2 Medium-Heavy"></td></tr>
    <tr class="MenuTableRow">
        <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">3 Medium-light</td>
        <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="3 Medium-light"></td></tr>
    <tr class="MenuTableRow">
        <td class="MenuEntryNameHover" nowrap="">4 Light</td>
        <td class="MenuEntryNoSubHover" arvalue="4-Light"></td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

So far to click any other element on this webpage I've been using:

```
Dim clickButton
Set clickButton= IE.document.getElementById("032345")
clickButton.Click
```

or doing the same but with .getElementsByClassName when no ID was avilable, which was working without any issues.

However with this menu I'm not able to use it for some reason, it just doesn't click anything unless I mouseover it manually, in which case it just clicks whichever option has a pointer over it, ignoring the class name and position completely.

I've also tried using the "MenuEntryNoSub" class thinking it might be some kind of invisible button but nothing happened either when I run the script.

for .getElementsByClassName it debug prints a proper TextContent for each of the elements with "MenuEntryName"

```
Debug.Print IE.document.getElementsByClassName("MenuEntryName")(1).textContent
```

however when I try to click it using the following code it does nothing:

```
Dim chooseOption
Set chooseOption = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("MenuEntryName")(1)
chooseOption.Click
```

Would greatly appreciate any pointers on what I might be doing wrong - Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there in image that overlays the dropdown, and that is what needs clicked? Perhaps change the elements value to an _Option_ of the dropdown, then perform the click.

Comment: This is the whole HTML content of the table, can't see any images in there or before the table either so would guess there's no images, but I could be wrong.

Could you please elaborate on what exactly do you mean by "change the elements value to an Option of the dropdown"?
(it doesn't appear to have any .Value, Debug.Print doesn't return anything for this element, it only returns .TextContent)

Comment: Is this webpage public? Something we can go to?

Comment: An url would be most helpful if available.

Comment: Sadly no, it's for internal use at my workplace only :(